# Magento 2 tinymce missing from pub/static

Tags: tinymce, magento2, magento-2.3

I'm getting a TinyMCE error on our admin site after upgrading from 2.2x to 2.3.5. Here are the errors I am seeing:

```
    static/version1599523842/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/tinymce.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

    1bf88a18ad7d25758b55791e3570de1a.js:166 Uncaught Error: Script error for: tinymce
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (1bf88a18ad7d25758b55791e3570de1a.js:166)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (1bf88a18ad7d25758b55791e3570de1a.js:1681)
```

I've deployed the static content, I've cleared the cache, I've cleared all the magemojo cache (redis, varnish, etc...) but I still get this error. I've searched around the M2 forum and the github repo but am not having much luck locating why that file wouldn't be available. Instead of the tinymce.js file, I see a tiny_mce_4 folder in pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US

Any ideas what I may be missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I was able to finally figure out what the issue was. I found that a module we had installed needed to be updated as it was using "tinymce". I found this by running the following command against our app/code folder:

```
grep -rnw 'app/code' -e 'tinymce'
```

Posting here in case anyone else runs into this issue.