# Backend page load and WYSIWYG issue after updating Magento 2

Tags: magento2

We have upgraded from 2.3.2 to 2.4.1 but are experiencing an issue in admin where sometimes you have to refresh the page for it to fully load, the menu on the left does not work when you click the icons and the WYSIWYG does not load. Have checked permissions and tried updating a few of the bigger modules to the latest version, but no luck.

Had anyone experienced the same issue?

I have posted console errors here https://ibb.co/R4LWWGD

Answer (score 1):

There might be a module that [still uses the old version of tinymce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63823608/941770)

```sh
    grep -rnw 'app/code' -e 'tinymce'
```

If there's nothing in your code namespace, try and grep the whole codebase plus vendor.

The library instanced in the wysiwyg is now mapped to 'tinymce4', see:

```
vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/requirejs-config.js
```

It might not be enough to simply add the 4, depends what the module does if that's the issue. I'll also go ahead on the presumption that you've already re-deployed statics or that you're in developer mode.

For the stylesheet refusal to load, you'll have to whitelist googleapi's domain for the style-src policy, [here's the devdocs to it.](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/security/content-security-policies.html#add-a-domain-to-the-whitelist)